# How can i make these custom dynamic sections in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Not sure if "custom dynamic sections" is the proper sentence to describe my desire. But I hope this description would tell you what I really need.

[image: Cooking template article section]

[image: cooking template article section]

As you can see in the screenshots above. It's a normal article in a cooking website, which contains two sections. The first one in the first picture is a dynamic sections for ingredients which is like a todo list and user can tick on each one as shown. Also he can adjust servings to double or trible the ingredients.
The second section is showing each step numbered.
All these are beside the normal paragraphs they can type anywhere.

Now the question is: What is the logic behind this? How to add different sections in the article **without plugins (i want to code it myself)**, for example is it custom fields or what? and how to make it dynamic to be like a todo list and adjusting servings. And steps.
That's all. How can I do these in my code?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of article that is. There are mainly three types of content in worpress: page, post and custom post. If it's page then you can go to 'pageName-page.php' to make custom edits or you can only change them from admin 'pages' option. And, if it's post or custom post, you can only change the content from the admin section i.e. for post you can browse the post and edit one of them.

As far as I can guess this should be a page, so find the page name and if their is file called 'pageName-page.php', then you can edit it.

Comment: It actually is not a page. It's a post. How can i make the custom post to be like this to have many sections with dynamic functionalities? Like the screenshots?

Comment: There is a plugin called Advanced custom fields, with this plugin you will be able to add a custom field to your custom post. You can add image, text, checkbox, date and so many others fields to your custom post, so this should give you what you want.